# How to deserialize nested list with RestTemplate?

Tags: java, serialization, resttemplate

I have a response which was get from calling RestTemplate. I have a problem in deserializing the response to the target class. I can get "code" and "message", but I can not get data as a list.
Here is the my response class and RestTemplate call.

```
public class DataResponse {
    Long code;
    String message;
    BusinessClusterData data;
    public class BusinessClusterData {
        @SerializedName("data")
        List<BusinessClusterContent> businessClusterContentList;
        Long count;
    }
}
ResponseEntity<DataResponse> response = 
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, DataResponse.class);
```

Here is the response.

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "ok",
    "data": {
        "data": [
        {
            "name": "test_name",
            "host": "test_host",
            "segInfo": [
            {
                "state": "applyed",
                "formId": 42158
            }
        ]}
      ],
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@JsonProperty` (`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`) instead of Gson's `@SerializedName` like

```
public class BusinessClusterData {
    @JsonProperty("data")
    List<BusinessClusterContent> businessClusterContentList;
    Long count;
}
```

Also i think you should make `BusinessClusterData` a static class, since it's not dependent on an instance of the `DataResponse`

Answer (score 0):

It works with @JsonProperty (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty):

```
public class DataResponse<T>
{
    protected Long code;
    ...
    @JsonProperty("data")
    protected List<T> list;
}
```

Deserialization sample:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<ResultList<BusinessClusterData>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResultList<BusinessClusterData>>() {};
ResponseEntity<ResultList<BusinessClusterData>> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, typeRef);
```